# Starting Celery remote debugger on exception

Tags: python, debugging, celery

I already know how to start a PDB console on any exception using `sys.excepthook`, and it has been over time a really valuable tool in my debugging workflow.

Is there a way to do the same in Celery when a task encounters an exception?

This would allow me to debug tasks without having to add a breakpoint, restart the worker and manually reproduce the bug each time something goes wrong.

I already tried using the `task_failed` signal, but the debugger is started after the task has exited, which does not preserve the stack trace and task state.